# Conditions under which an Convolution operator is normal.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convolution

I have a possibly complex valued convolution operator given by

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}K(x-y)f(y)dy$

I know that the operator is self-adjoint if

$K(x)=\overline{K(-x)}$

holds. But are there softer conditions under which the operator is only normal?
Every time I want to find conditions I only get the same as in the self-adjoint case.

Thanks for all ideas and helps.

Comment: if $K[f](x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x-y) f(y) dy$ then $K^*[f](x) \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{K(y-x)} f(y) dy$ so $KK^* = K^* K \implies \ldots$ note that another way would be to write $K = W D W^*$ where $W^*$ is the Fourier transform operator, so $K^* = W D^* W$ and $\ldots$

Comment: thanks. I get that $D=D^{*}$ has to hold. But this is equivalent to

$WK=-\overline{WK}$ and this again holds if $K(x)=\overline{K(-x)}$.

Comment: no you are wrong, a convolution operator is always normal (it is always diagonal in the unitary Fourier basis)

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I think i understand your argumentation. And calculated the unitary decomposition and get that the Multiplicationoperator $D$ is given by $ \sqrt{2 \pi}WK$. This always holds, right?

I also calculated $KK^{*}=K^{*}K$ directly by convolution integral and it works finally:)))